# Julia: How can I write to a specific page of an acrobat pdf?

Tags: pdf, acrobat, julia

I am stuck trying to create an acrobat pdf of more than one page in Julia

I am currently using the following code to create a table of plots:

```
t[1,1] = p1;
t[2,1] = p2;
t[3,1] = p3;
t[4,1] = p4;
file(t,"Daily.pdf");
```

But the file function squeezes them all on one page. Is there a way to tell it to use multiple pages, or split the table up into multiple pages and tell the file function to write each table to a specific page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Julia packages are you using?

Comment: I am using Winston for graphing.    Others are DataFrames, Cairo, Dates, Debug, IJulia. Thanks